# How do I add a method to Array#size?

Tags: ruby

I want to add a `one?` method to `Array#size` so that can I say:

```
class Array
  def one?
    self.size == 1
  end
end

[1].size.one?
 #=> true
[1,2].size.one?
 #=> false
```

Comment: that's not a class method, it's an instance method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you see `class` of `[1].size`, it is `Fixnum`, so If you want to chain `one?` function on `[1].size`, you will have to define this for `Fixnum` class as well, like following:

```
class Fixnum
  def one?
    self == 1
  end
end
```

Now following will also work:

```
[1].size.one?
#=> true
[1,2].size.one?
#=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `size` returns a Fixnum, it must be defined there for it work properly.

```
class Fixnum
  def one?
    self == 1
  end
end

[1].size.one?
#=> true
```

*Why the same answer?*
**Posted at the same time as other answer, so decided to leave it up.**

Comment: Why are you posting the same answer?